# Magento filter product by custom text

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I am trying to filter product with custom text. I have create one module Top Searched product. In this module i am adding Top searched keyword like..

```
1. Shirt
2. jeans
3. Dress
```

etc.

So in Top Searched module i have list of these keyword. Now i want to filter search result list with these keyword. Also i want to add these to layered navigation.

Let say i am on search result page `www.demo.com/?q=women`
Now when i will click on dress on left filter section of my Top search keyword list, it will check dress keyword in product title and list all product with matched keyword Dress in product title with `?q=women`.

I hope some one help me on this issue.
Thanks,

Comment: Hello Richa, I am trying something similar. But still no luck.  I hope someone help here. Thanks